# Search through an ArrayList of Objects that have a value of an attribute within a certain range

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I am expanding my learning in Java.

I wanted to create some sort of match making system, like they have in games & other related applications.

In some point in this system I want to search for "players" in queue within a certain range of a rating value, I have a couple of methods that come to mind of doing this.

```
public Player findClosePlayerInQueue(int rating) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while(true) {
        int range = 100;
        for(Player p: queuedPlayers) {
            if (p.getRating() > rating - range && p.getRating() < rating + range ) {
                System.out.printf("Searching took: %.3f", (startTime - System.nanoTime())/1e9 );
                return p;
            }
        }
        range += 100;
    }
}
```

And this is another method, given a specific range that it has to meet.

```
public Player findClosestPlayerInQueue(int rating, int range) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while(true) {
        for(Player p: queuedPlayers) {
            if (p.getRating() > rating - range && p.getRating() < rating + range ) {
                System.out.printf("Searching took: %.3f", (startTime - System.nanoTime())/1e9 );
                return p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, given that players could join the queue at any point, these will be threaded somehow.

Finally, my question is, is this the best way of going about these functions? I have searched around, but can't find anything relevant when applying a range.

*Irrelevant extra information:* I realise that strictly speaking this isn't range, since I don't half the value, but that's not what I'm trying to work out here. Also another thing to note is that queuedPlayers will be ordered by the length that they have been in queue

Comment: Is using Java 8 an option?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Given the correct explanations, yes, not really looked into it yet though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a good way of looking for the best match for three reasons:

- Your first method takes too long when you need a significant number of `+= 100` increments on the range before finding a player
- Even when your first method returns, it may not return the best match
- Your second method may never return, if there is no player who falls into the specific range.

What you should do instead is measuring the "distance" from a specific `rating`. In this case, the distance is simply `Math.abs(p.getRating() - rating)`. Remember the player with the best distance, go through the queue only once, and will always return the best match:

```
public Player findClosePlayerInQueue(int rating) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int bestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Player res = null;
    for(Player p: queuedPlayers) {
        int dist = Math.abs(p.getRating() - rating);
        if (dist < bestDistance ) {
            bestDistance = dist;
            res = p;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Searching took: %.3f", (startTime-System.nanoTime())/1e9);
    return res;
}
```

When your rating is eventually expanded to include other things, you can change the distance measure as well to operate in `N` dimensions. You could use the *Euclidean distance*, the [*Manhattan Distance*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance), or any other distance that you think is an appropriate measure of the desired "closeness".

Comment: I understand that a player may not be found, that's part of the point, but obviously for the first instance the range will increase, then when a new player joins the queue they will be picked, which is bad.

I guess I could give a certain time limit and if no one better joins within say 2 minutes then just pick the closest possible, based on their distance.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's best not to hang in a loop though until that happens and to check again when another player joins the queue

Answer (score 2):

You know, if you use more than one variable to match the other player, you may find interesting the idea of searching the other player that is the "nearest".

For example, you're comparing using the "rating" variable. It's a single variable comparison.

But what if you had more variables to compare your players, like strenght, agility, etc etc etc and compare them all at the same time?

If you think on a multi-variable comparison, you could use something like KNN to find a group of players that are "closer" to yours, and then you could just pick up one of this group.

There's a full KNN java code example and explanation here

http://afewguyscoding.com/2010/05/nearest-neighbors-java/

Comment: In note to this, the "rating" value eventually will be an Object that stores multiple stats as you say. This could be a possibility, would also be a great way to gather information from the results I see as well! Thanks

Comment: In this case, I think KNN can be a good option. :-) the algorithm is simple and robust. And all you'll have to do is to choose a way to calculate the "distance" between your objects

Answer (score 2):

If you are going for efficiency, you can keep the queue sorted at all times according to the rating of players. Then you can improve greatly on lookup efficiency by performing [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Roughly speaking, the binary search goes like this:

1. You take a player from the middle of the queue and compare his rating to the desired interval.
2. If the player fits in the interval, you've got your solution.
3. If the player is weaker, you reduce the search to the upper half of the queue.
4. If the player is stronger, you reduce the search to the lower half.

Repeat until you find the player, or until the size of searched block is reduced to 1 (in case no such player exists in queue). If such a player exists, you can find him in log(N) comparisons, N being the number of players in queue

Comment: Won't sorting just take as long?

Comment: @andyroo He suggests keeping the queue sorted, which can be done cheaper than sorting each time that you search.

Comment: Nope, the cost of adding a new player is also just log(N) and you don't have to sort it over again after each new player.